# Создание массив объектов класса и проверить их

Tags: c++, ооп

Задание : «Треугольник» Необходимо следить за непротиворечивостью состояния объекта
(Проверять треугольник на существование).
Данные класса: длины сторон треугольника.
Функции класса: сравнение двух треугольников, вычисление площади и
периметра треугольника, проверка, есть ли треугольник прямоугольным, равнобедренным,
равносторонним.
Создать массив объектов, вывести информацию обо всех равносторонних
треугольников.

Не могу понять, как правильно создать массив объектов.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;


 class treygol
 {
 public:

double a;
double b;
double c;
double s;
void Print()
{
    cout << "Вы ввели стороны треугольника=" << "\nПервая сторона-" << a << 
"\nВторая сторона -" << b << "\nТретья сторона-" << c << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void proverka()
{
    if ((a + b > c) && (b + c > a) && (c + a > b))
    {
        cout << "Треугольник может существовать" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Треуголник не существует" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void square()
{
    double p;
    p = (a + b + c) / 2;
    s = sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
    cout << "Площадь треугольника=" << s << endl;
}

void perimetr()
{
    double P;
    P = a + b + c;
    cout << "Периметр треугольника =" << P << endl;
}

void proverka2()
{
    if ((a == b) || (a == c) || (b == c))
    {
        cout << "Треугольник равнобедреннфый" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Треугольник не является равнобедренным" << endl;
    }

    if (a * a == b * b + c * c)
    {
        cout << "Треугольник прямоугольный" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Треугольник не является прямоугольным" << endl;
    }

    if (a==b&&b==c)
    {
        cout << "Треугольник равносторонний" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Треугольник не является равностороним" << endl;
    }
}
};

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

treygol treygolnic;
cout << "Введите первую сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic.a;
cout << "Введите вторую сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic.b;
cout << "Введите третью сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic.c;
treygolnic.proverka();
treygolnic.Print();
treygolnic.square();
treygolnic.perimetr();
treygolnic.proverka2();

treygol treygolnic2;
cout << "Введите первую сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic2.a;
cout << "Введите вторую сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic2.b;
cout << "Введите третью сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic2.c;
treygolnic2.proverka();
treygolnic2.Print();
treygolnic2.square();
treygolnic2.perimetr();
treygolnic2.proverka2();

if (treygolnic.s == treygolnic2.s)
{
    cout << "Треугольники одинаковые";
}

}
```

Comment: Пишите функцию с двумя аргументами типа `treygol`, а дальше вам нужно выбрать, как передавать эти параметры. По значению, по ссылке (`&`), по указателю (`*`).

Answer (score 1):

Можно определить оператор сравнения (`operator==`) для класса. Тогда можно сравнивать объекты этого класса с помощью обычного сравнения (`==`). Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class treygol
{
public:

double a;
double b;
double c;

void Print()
{
    cout << "Вы ввели стороны треугольника=" << "\nПервая сторона-" << a << "\nВторая сторона -" << b 
<< "\nТретья сторона-" << c << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void proverka()
{
    if ((a + b > c) && (b + c > a) && (c + a > b))
    {
        cout << "Треугольник может существовать" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Треуголник не существует" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

  bool operator ==(const treygol &that) const
  {
    return a == that.a && b == that.b && c == that.c;
  }
};

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

treygol treygolnic;
cout << "Введите первую сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic.a;
cout << "Введите вторую сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic.b;
cout << "Введите третью сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic.c;
treygolnic.proverka();
treygolnic.Print();

treygol treygolnic2;
cout << "Введите первую сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic2.a;
cout << "Введите вторую сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic2.b;
cout << "Введите третью сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> treygolnic2.c;
treygolnic2.proverka();
treygolnic2.Print();

  if(treygolnic2 == treygolnic)
    cout << "Равны" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Не равны" << endl;
}
```

С точки зрения ООП было бы лучше сделать так (сделать члены класса private и инициализировать их в констркуторе):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class treygol
{
double a;
double b;
double c;

public:
treygol( double init_a, double init_b, double init_c ) : a(init_a), b(init_b), c(init_c) {}

void Print()
{
    cout << "Вы ввели стороны треугольника=" << "\nПервая сторона-" << a << "\nВторая сторона -" << b 
<< "\nТретья сторона-" << c << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void proverka()
{
    if ((a + b > c) && (b + c > a) && (c + a > b))
    {
        cout << "Треугольник может существовать" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Треуголник не существует" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

  bool operator ==(const treygol &that) const
  {
    return a == that.a && b == that.b && c == that.c;
  }
};

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

double a;
double b;
double c;

cout << "Введите первую сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите вторую сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> b;
cout << "Введите третью сторону первого треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> c;

treygol treygolnic(a, b, c);
treygolnic.proverka();
treygolnic.Print();

cout << "Введите первую сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите вторую сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> b;
cout << "Введите третью сторону второго треугольника=" << endl;
cin >> c;

treygol treygolnic2(a, b, c);
treygolnic2.proverka();
treygolnic2.Print();

  if(treygolnic2 == treygolnic)
    cout << "Равны" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Не равны" << endl;
}
```

Comment: А если стороны одного - 3 4 5, а второго - 4 5 3, то они разные?...

Comment: Вопрос с тегами C++ и ООП и я ответил как реализовать сравнение с точки зрения языка. Я сделал простое сравнение где каждая сторона должна быть равна соответствующей (a равно a и т.д.). А так Вы правы, сравнивать надо разные комбинации.